# Installation of rabbitmq on windows 10 32bit

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using windows 10 32bit version.
I had previously installed erlang OTP 19.0 , rabbitmq and management web api plugin using cmd commands. But I was unable to access localhost:15672. Then I reinstalled both and now I am unable to start the server.
[Receiving this on cmd while trying to start the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwC0x.png)

C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.2\sbin>rabbitmq-server start
.
.
.

Error: Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...init terminating in do_boot ()

[image]

Comment: Do you set RabbitMQ environment variables? In the screenshot, the path to log files contains in fact two paths separated by a space.

Comment: could you post the error as plain text? This could be better for everyone.

Comment: Yes I have already set  the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue

Try to uninstall RabbitMQ server and Erlang ver 19 
Also delete the contents in the %AppData%Roaming/RabbitMQ..

Install erlang 18.0 from here http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_win32_18.1.exe
And then install the latest version of RabbitMQ (I installed 3.6.3).

Comment: Thanks @bharadwaj Sampath. But When I try to delete the content folder of erlang ver 19.0, an  error occurs. The error is- " can not delete epmd.exe as file is already in use by some other program".

Comment: Stop the RabbitMQ server in the services (by gng to services.msc and stopping the service) and try again.
Even uninstalling RabbitMQ can solve the problem.
Also , do not try to delete the files in the erlang folder , instead uninstall erlang from the programs.